# Compress-Archive powershell command not known in windows 7

Tags: powershell

I want to compress my database mysql to schedule a backup, I have used this powershell command in .bat file:

```
powershell -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -Command "Compress-Archive -Path C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.17\data\khalilbase\* -DestinationPath C:\wamp\www\tester_compress"
```

I have an error Compress-Archive command is unknown knowing  I use windows 7 64bits
I also tested directly in powershell window but same error:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

`Compress-Archive` is only available with PS v4 onwards.

Check your powershell version using `$PSVersionTable` as you'll likely still be on PS v2 with Windows 7 unless you've [upgraded WMF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/wmf/5.1/install-configure).

---

I assume there's a reason you're using Command Prompt rather than the Powershell Console? This just adds another unnecessary step to everything...

CMD:

```
powershell -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -Command "$PSVersionTable"
```

PS Console:

```
$PSVersionTable
```